# Why is the derivative of $\bf (a^Tx)(b^Tx)=ab^T+ba^T$ and not $2ab^T$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\bf a^Tx$ is a scalar value. So $\bf a^Tx=x^Ta$ so $\bf (a^Tx)(b^Tx)=x^Tab^Tx$ which is in quadratic form. So differentiating this gets $2\bf ab^T$

However, the book says it is $ab^T+ba^T$

Comment: Never mind, The equation $f'(x)=2Qx$ for a quadratic holds only if Q is symetric, which is not necessairy here.

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @littleO done :)

Answer (score 0):

actually, given any square matrix $M$ and the quadratic form $x^T Mx$ acting on a column vector $x,$ the gradient (as a column) is
$$  (M + M^T) x  $$

Answer (score 0):

For the quadratic equation:

$$f({\bf x}) = {\bf x}^TA{\bf x}$$
The derivative is actually 
$$\nabla_x f({\bf x}) = (A^T+A){\bf x}$$

It just happens that when $A$ is symetric (i.e $A=A^T$), we have that

$$\nabla_x f({\bf x}) = (2A){\bf x}$$

Since there are no restrictions on $a,b$ in the question, we have to use the transpose version.